# UI-GRID - Convert A Cell To Date Format

Tags: angular-ui-grid

Is there a way in UI-GRID to convert the column from a long value to a Date String?

Is there a way todo this without having to loop through each value?

Comment: var date = new Date(yourValue) for one value;
In $http service when you're getting a response you can do such as `data[i].createdDate= new Date(data[i].createdDate);` in a loop or forEach, It would be better than having lots of function calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping, you can add a cell template to the column which has the date field.

```
cellTemplate:'<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">{{grid.appScope.showDate(123123123)}}</div>'
```

and create a showDate method in your scope

```
$scope.showDate = function(value)
{
  return new Date(value);
}
```

You can format your date in the showDate.